# I would like to do deep suspend and resume using bash script "echo "mem" > /sys/power/state"

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

Deep suspend and resume I want to execute with a bash script. When I run the script its hangs but when I run the command on the terminal it works fine.

```
root@linux:~# cat sus-res.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo +30> /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm

echo "mem" > /sys/power/state
```

When I use this script the system hanges

```
root@linux:~# ./sus-res.sh
[154170.741075] PM: suspend entry (deep)
[154170.751049] Filesystems sync: 0.006 seconds
[154170.758511] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[154170.768866] OOM killer disabled.
```

When I execute these commands on the terminal its works fine

```
root@linux:~# echo +30> /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
root@linux:~# echo "mem" > /sys/power/state
[  110.843594] PM: suspend entry (deep)
[  110.861224] Filesystems sync: 0.013 seconds
[  110.871295] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[  110.881433] OOM killer disabled.
[  110.884695] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[  110.894771] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  111.052693] fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
[  111.056173] PM: suspend devices took 0.150 seconds
[  111.082157] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  111.105310] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  111.109588] CPU1 is up
[  111.111874] CPU2 is up
[  111.114307] CPU3 is up
[  111.433514] PM: resume devices took 0.290 seconds
[  111.440542] fsl-ssi-dai 2028000.ssi: No cache defaults, reading back from HW
[  111.470426] OOM killer enabled.
[  111.473589] Restarting tasks ... done.
[  111.481551] random: crng reseeded on system resumption
[  111.487234] PM: suspend exit
[  111.631674] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[  114.240254] fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
root@linux:~#
```

Thank you for suggestions

Comment: Not a solution, but maybe a first step for debugging: doing `echo 1 > /sys/power/pm_debug_messages` could (maybe) give you a bit more details about the step that makes it hang. (If `pm_debug_messages` file is not available, you will need to compile your kernel with `CONFIG_PM_DEBUG=y`, if I remember well)

Comment: Add a space before `>` and run your script with `&` at the end. Then tell us if it helped.